# jQuery .load() opens script in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery code that loads in a HTML file which includes an script. The problem is that the script gets opened in a new tab instead getting displayed in its `div` where it needs to be.

Script that loads contact in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cont').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        $("#content").hide();
        $('#home').removeClass("active");
        $('#info').removeClass("active");
        $('#vergun').removeClass("active");
        $('#pasp').removeClass("active");
        $('#cont').addClass("active");
        $("#content").show();
        $("#content").load("contact.html"); 
      });
});
```

contact.html

```
 <div id="contents">
    <h2>Adres</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td id="tableSpacer"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></td><td id="tableSpacer"><a href="tel:734-389-7473">734-389-7473</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></td><td>25 Woodland Drive </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" >28803 Megaton, Commonwealth</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
          <td id="tableSpacerTop"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></td><td id="tableSpacerTop">info@megaton.nl</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
        <div id="contentMail">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/mail/script/mail.js"></script>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Code where it loads into

```
<center>
    <div id="content" style="position: static;">
        <div id="contents"></div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Code that triggers the script

```
<a class="menuItem" id="cont" href="#">Contact</a>
```

What it needs to look like
[image: What it needs to look like]

What happens
[image: what happens]

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that `#cont` element you used for the selector on click function is a link so you need to use `preventDefault()` before anything else

Comment: What you're doing now is opening contact.html if I'm right. You have to load it on the same page.

Comment: @BatuZet when using `event.preventDefault();` it does nothing

Comment: @AmandoVledder did you place `event` parameter inside function? Like `$('#cont').click(function(event)...` If you did then there is something else. We need to see your base html code too

Comment: `$('#cont').click(function(event)...` must be inside `onLoad` or `document.Ready` or `function(){}`

Comment: @PranavSingh it is in a `document.Ready` forgot to include it in the post

Comment: @AmandoVledder are you sure you put an `id` on that link with the value of `"cont"` ?

Comment: @BatuZet yes `<a class="menuItem" id="cont" href="#">Contact</a>`

Comment: @AmandoVledder — After your edit, there is no evidence of you using the event parameter at all.  (You also haven't included the HTML which the event handler binds to)

Comment: @AmandoVledder - What's inside `mail.js`?

Comment: @BatuZet http://pastebin.com/sy9DPmrm

Comment: Try Changing anchor tag <a> to div.

Comment: @PranavSingh using `<div class="menuItem" id="cont" href="#">Contact</div>` it does the same

Comment: @AmandoVledder I guess the problem is you used `$("#content").load() ` which actually should be `$("#contents").load()`

Comment: @BatuZet it still loads it in a new tab when loading it into `contents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probems is in your *mail.js* contents:
you are using **document.write(** instead of **$('#contents').html(**

So you are replacing all the stuff in the document.
**See line 37 of your *mail.js* file.**